# Maximum call stack exceeded error in ReactJS. Can someone help explain what's going on? (Snippet on JSFiddle)

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS and was trying my hands on a simple project. Basically, the snippet create a list of friends from an array and displays the total number of friends.

For some reason, I realized the incrementFriendsCount function throws a "Maximum call stack exceeded error" when I add a new friend

The code snippet below is also [available on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jwan622/kb3gN/12272/).

```js
var HelloUser = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      name: "Toyosi",
      friends: ["Susanna", "Jibola", "Worreva"],
      friendsCount: 0
    }
  },
  addFriends: function(friend) {
    this.setState({
      friends: this.state.friends.concat([friend])
    });
  },
  componentWillMount: function() {
    this.setState({
      friendsCount: this.state.friends.length
    });
  },
  incrementFriendsCount: function() {
    this.setState({
      friendsCount: this.state.friends.length
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return ( < div >
      Villain: {
        this.state.name
      }, No of friends: {
        this.state.friendsCount
      } < br / >
      < AddingTheFriend addNew = {
        this.addFriends
      }
      incCount = {
        this.incrementFriendsCount
      }
      />
        <ListFriends enemies={this.state.friends} / >
      < /div>
    );
  }
});

var ListFriends = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
     enemies: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
    },
    render: function() {
     var allFriends = this.props.enemies.map(function(friend){
         return <li>{friend}</li > ;
    });

  return ( < div > Her evil friends:
    < ul > {
      allFriends
    } < /ul>
            </div >
  )
}
});

var AddingTheFriend = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          newFriend: ''
        }
      },
      propTypes: {
        addNew: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
      },
      updateNewFriend: function(change) {
        this.setState({
          newFriend: change.target.value
        });
      },
      addTheFriend: function() {
        this.props.addNew(this.state.newFriend);
        this.setState({
          newFriend: ''
        })
      },
      componentWillReceiveProps: function() {
        this.props.incCount();
      },
      render: function() {
          return ( < div >
            < input type = "text"
            value = {
              this.state.newFriend
            }
            onChange = {
              this.updateNewFriend
            }
            />
                <button type="button" onClick={this.addTheFriend}>Add Friend</button >
            < /div>
        )
    }
});
React.render(<HelloUser / > , document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="http://fb.me/react-js-fiddle-integration.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

I will appreciate if anyone could throw more light on why this error is thrown.

Comment: It's working fine for me. The only warning I'm seeing is regarding `className` (see: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are calling `this.props.incCount` in `componentWillReceiveProps` which sets the state of the parent component and the effect will be that `AddingTheFriend` is rendered again, and `this.props.incCount` is called again. Hence the stack overflow.

Another advice would be that generally you want to be careful and use `setState` as little as possible, in as few components as possible. Simply increment the friends count at the same time you concat the new friend to parent component's state.

Here's the [codepen](http://codepen.io/romseguy/pen/ZbOwdg?editors=101) --much better than JSFiddle in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks @romseguy. Your solution works well. I noticed a refactor in the code without the this.ref. I understand the current solution better. My biggest take away here is to reduce the number of `setState`s I call before the render function.

Answer (score 12):

As a future reference for people with the same error output when using react:
This error will also occur of you run your app with both

- webpack-dev-server --hot
- new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()

So: When you run your server with --hot and also have the hotModuleReplacementPlugin enabled in your webpack config then you will get into the situation that your components will recursively update, thus generating exactly the error message the OP mentioned.

Simple solution: Omit one of the two things, e.g. omit the "--hot" since you already use the plugin for that.

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was an infinite loop, or if you like an obvious logical error.