# Maximum call stack exceeded error in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class Game extends React.Component{

        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                history: [{
                    squares: Array(9).fill(null)
                }],
                xIsNext: true,
                stepNumber : 0,
                xScore : 0,
                oScore : 0,
            };
        }

        updateScore(winner){
            if(winner == 'X'){
                this.setState({
                    xScore : this.state.xScore + 1
                });
            }else if(winner == 'O'){
                console.log(this.state.oScore);
            }
        }

        render(){
            const history = this.state.history;
            const current = history[this.state.stepNumber];
            const winner = calculateWinner(current.squares);

            const moves = history.map((step, move) => {
                const desc = move ? 'Move #' + move : 'Game start';

                return (
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</a>
                        </li>
                );
            });

            let status;
            if (winner) {
                status = 'Winner : ' + winner;
                this.updateScore(winner);
            } else {
                status = 'Next player: ' + (this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');
            }

            return(
                <div className="game">
                    <div className="game-board">
                        <Board squares={current.squares}
                               onClick={(i) => this.handleClick(i)}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="game-info">
                        <div>{status}</div>
                        <ol>{moves}</ol>
                    </div>
                    <div className="score-board">
                        Score Board
                        <div className="xScore">
                            X : {this.state.xScore}
                        </div>
                        <div className="oScore">
                            O : {this.state.oScore}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
```

[Click here](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html#wrapping-up) for the entire demo code and application. This is the first tutorial I am working on. I wish to add some of my own features. I want to add a score board in this game. But I am not able to update the scores.

I am confused why am I getting a stack overflow.
This question might seem redundant, but the other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716885/maximum-call-stack-exceeded-error-in-reactjs-can-someone-help-explain-whats-go) dont help me for some reason. Please throw some light.

[Live Demo](https://aakashrshah.github.io/projects/react/src/demos/01_day/day1.html) of the scoreboard giving a garbage value. X needs to win to reproduce the error.

What is the solution?

Comment: `the other answers` which other answers - searching for "stack overflow" on stack overflow must be hard though!!!

Comment: `render` calls `updateScore` which calls `setState` which calls `render` ...

Comment: @cartant should I make another component for Score Board? Thanks.

Comment: Well, whatever you decide to do, I think the important thing is to not mutate state in `render`.

Comment: The code appears to be missing some functions including `handleClick`. Move winner calculation logic into that and your problem should be solved.